# How to access one web application from another in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have solution with 3 projects. One is Website and another one is Services. I want to access page from Services project via AJAX from page on Website but i fail to do so since only one project it running.

How can it be done?

**please avoid answers like "What have you tried ?" because this is general question with no relation to specific code.**

I'm using IIS Express built-in with Visual Studio Express 2012.

Thanks

Comment: are you running without debugging or with debugging ?

Comment: With but i select certain application.

Comment: Why not run the other services in IIS instead?

Comment: @eugeneK , start all the project `without debugging[Ctrl+F5]` and then attach your debugger to the worker process for debugging.

Comment: @Furqan, this is what i was trying to avoid.

Comment: @AshwinSingh, i don't want to mess with local IIS unless i must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by specifying multiple start up projects.
Select the properties of the solution, go to `Common Properties` -> `Startup Project`.
Select `Multiple Startup Projects` and select the ones you need. You can also adjust the starting order.

Having said that, IIs Express serves up web applications even if Visual Studio is in debug mode or not, so this isn't strictly necessary.

*Note: I don't have the Express SKU in front  of me, so no guarantees that this is possible on that. If it isn't, then the answer is that it isn't possible.*

Comment: how do i create urls between two projects ? I mean there will be always different port number.

Comment: The port number is specified in the project properties, so it's not changing. Once set, it's up to you to change it, so there shouldn't be an issue.